# Not Able to Run get_session_tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand why I am getting an error in tf.get_session_tensor.

Below is my code:

https://github.com/subhobrata/Deep-Learning/blob/master/Untitled1.ipynb

Please help me with this error.

Comment: Please include all the most important parts of the question, such as the code that's causing the problem, in the question itself. External pages can change or become inaccessible.

Comment: sure you are correct, I will take of it in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared type float32 in :

`p, a = tf.get_session_tensor(h.handle, tf.float32)`

however c is of type int, so you should declare it as such

`p, a = tf.get_session_tensor(h.handle, tf.int32)`

or change its type to float